# Safari Image Size Auto Height CSS

Tags: css

I am testing this problem in the latest version of Safari for Windows 7.

The problem is that this code works in all other browsers BUT safari:

```
 <style type="text/css">
    .userImg { height: 100%; width: 100%; }
    .imgContainer { height: auto; width: 150px; }
 </style>

 <div class="imgContainer">
    <img id="img" class="userImg" src="TemplateFiles/Hydrangeas.jpg" alt="" />
 </div>
```

Does anyone know of a trick to get this to size the image proportionally in Safari using just CSS?

Thanks!

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Just set only the width on the image. The browser will scale the image proportionally automatically.

```
.userImg { width: 100%; }
.imgContainer { height: auto; width: 150px; }​
```

Comment: On Safari iOS it doesn't scale proportionally :|

Answer (score 123):

For those who **needs to use height auto** and **parent of image is set to display: flex**, this trick will help.

```
image { align-self: flex-start; }
```

If your **parent of image has set flex-direction: column**, you need to do this instead.

```
image { justify-self: flex-start; }
```

Comment: Amazing, I had this problem just now and the solution was your answer form yesterday to a question from 8 years ago. Could this be a new bug in Safari?

Comment: Haha I guess good timing. **But I wouldn't say it's a bug.** Safari is known to act differently in many cases than other known browsers but those aren't bugs. When you set display flex, it also assign some other properties to it's children. Initial value of flex childrens for **align-items** is **stretch**. **My guess** is that due to that, the image probably ignores the height you set and the aspect ratio is then broken.

Comment: Just hit this with a flexed image in Safari in 2020 too, ty David!

Comment: Thank you @DavidVoráč! I'll pay anyone who can tell me *why* Safari behaves in this perplexing way. Is it spec compliant? Safari is the one browser I would celebrate being eaten up into Google's Blink empire.

Comment: The should be the accepted solution! Still a valid fix in 2020

Comment: Yep, just fixed for me too in December 2020. I'm actually surprised it worked lol.

Comment: Wow, important thing i learned. Thank you

Comment: Thanks, using `align-self: center` also solves the problem.

Comment: Also checking in December 2020 haha - works as advertised! Just one more CSS quirk to cement to the brain

Comment: I wish could upvote this twice. It just caught me out again ‍

Answer (score 7):

For those who needs to use **height auto** you an also try with this :

```
.userImg{
    object-fit: contain;
}
```

Answer (score 4):

```
.userImg { width: 100%; height: auto; }
.imgContainer { width: 150px; }​
```

2019 year.
check maybe the parent element

```
.imgContainer { display: flex; align-items: stretch}
```

Answer (score 2):

Try this:
Parent has display:flex
Child has align-self:center

```css
@import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Slabo+27px');
body {
  font-family: "Slabo 27px", serif;
}
h2 {
  text-align: center;
}
[data-flex] {
  display: flex;
  width: 80%;
  max-width: 800px;
  font-size: 1.2rem;
  margin: 0 auto;
  line-height: 1.5;
}
[data-flex] > img {
  margin-right: 2rem;
  width: 30%;
}
[data-center] {
  align-items: center;
}
[data-flex] div, [data-flex] p {
  flex: 1;
}
[data-flex] div {
  margin-right: 2rem;
}
[data-flex] div img {
  width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<base href="https://s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/s.cdpn.io/4273/">
<h2>By default, images that are flex-children will be their <em>natural</em> height, regardless of their width:</h2>
<div data-flex>
  <img src="sophie.jpg" alt>
</div>
<h2>This can be avoided by <em>not</em> specifying a width for the image, but that makes it non-responsive:</h2>
<div data-flex>
  <img src="sophie.jpg" alt style="width: auto">
</div>
<h2>Solution 1: apply <code>align-self: center</code> to the image</h2>
<div data-flex>
  <img src="sophie.jpg" alt style="align-self: center">
</div>

<h2>Solution 2: apply <code>align-items: center</code> to the flex container</h2>
<div data-flex data-center>
  <img src="sophie.jpg" alt>
</div>

<h2>Solution 3: Place the image inside another container, and make <em>that</em> the flex-child</h2>

<div data-flex data-center>
  <div>
  <img src="sophie.jpg" alt>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Seems to work in both Safari and Chrome...

```
.container: {
 height={"100%"}
 display="contents"
}

.image: {
 height={"100%"}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I encountered a similar issue with controlling the width of images in my project. I found that setting the CSS `overflow` property to `hidden` on the `img` element effectively resolved the issue. Here's how I applied it:

```css
.images-contaner {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  max-height: 126px;
}
img {
  margin-right: 4px;
  max-height: calc(25% - 4px);
  overflow: hidden;
}
```