# SVG is not displayed in Safari (Ipad, Iphone). What is the reason?

Tags: html, css, svg

https://jsfiddle.net/918znr8q/

If you ask `height: auto;`, in safari image height is zero, ie, SVG does not appear. Why?

How to force the browser to display correctly?

Comment: possible solution http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10760243/safari-image-size-auto-height-css

Comment: That's one hell of a .svg... Is this just an example you've used, or is your embedded raster image your actual svg you're using?

Comment: @Matthew Lock

1.Yes, the bitmap should be the task condition.
2. http://jsfiddle.net/918znr8q/3 There were extra margins at the top and bottom. 
 
And Safari still does not show anything.